# How to safely use reverso with ferrata harness?

Tags: safety, climbing, rappelling, belaying, safety-standards

Ferrata harnesses (FH) can be probably *safely used also for climbing*, as stated in another 
[post](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14851/can-i-re-use-a-via-ferrata-carabiner-harness-for-climbing).

However, I am not sure how to use the reverso with FH.
This is because  in a [usual FH](http://besthiking.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/71NKyr2jQ7L._SL1000_.jpg),
the belay loop is rotated by 90 degrees, 
w.r.t. the [common climbing harness](https://www.rei.com/learn/expert-advice/climbing-harness/_jcr_content/images/image0.img.jpg/Anatomy%20of%20a%20climbing%20harness.jpg) (CCH).
This will make the reverso slightly flip accordingly 
and therefore
 *not [facing the wall](http://cdn.outdoorgearlab.com/photos/13/84/259932_26586_XL.jpg)*, 
but rather the side of the person belaying.

I am wondering if this is really a safety issue and if there is a technique to prevent it (like for instance using a 
[locking-quick-draw](http://www.karstendelap.com/2012/10/20/the-locking-quick-draw/), that would allow for more flexibility and therefore also for a reasonable angle w.r.t the wall - ~90 degrees)

Comment: Older climbing harnesses used to use this system. It was moved basically for comfort when belaying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not done any formal testing and am hesitant to recommend such an arrangement, however over the past 15 years climbing I have in many situations either used or seen others use such harnesses and had no concerns around how belay devices sit.  I've never seen any issue in this arrangement and can't imagine it, you may just want to lock off slightly more to one side rather than directly between your legs.

In saying this, before trusting this in a critical system test it in a safe manner and ensure you are comfortable, or have a backup set up.